# Virtualbox Networking - Accessing VPN & Guest OS

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, windows-server-2008, virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox 4.1.22 on a Windows 7 (64bit) host, with a Windows Server 2008 (64bit) guest OS. The VM is configured with 4 network adapters in the order of NAT, Bridged (LAN), Bridged (WiFi), & Bridged (MS Virtual WiFi).

When working at the office, on a wired network, I'm able to access network resources & the internet from the guest. I can also access website hosted on the guest from the host's browsers.

However, when working from home, using a WiFi router connected to the internet through 3G, connected to my company's VPN, I'm only able to access the network resources from the host. The guest can access the internet, but not the resources on the VPN. Also, I'm unable to access the sites on the guest from the host.

I have even tried to connect to the same VPN on the guest but it would not even connect. I have also disabled the Firewall on the guest without success. I have also tried setting the promiscuous mode on each adapter to "Allow All". The last adapter was changed to a host-only adapter also without success.

Can anyone please assist?

Edit - So the solution was to disable the bridged adapter to my wifi interface adapter. I noticed while trying to configure some parts on my 3G WiFi router that it listed my virtual machine as a connected device. Instead of using the NAT networking mode it directly connected to my router and to the web.

However, I'm still unable to access the sites hosted on the guest from the host...